# Avoiding Denormals in Haxe

Tags: signal-processing, multimedia, haxe

I am doing DSP in Haxe. Some of my DSP includes recursive algorithms that may generate denormal (aka subnormal) numbers. Some platforms perform poorly when encountering such numbers, making real-time processing impossible (and even offline processing, in some cases, dramatically more difficult). Obviously, only algorithms that produce very small numbers (eg, via recursive multiplication) are effected, but I am working with these.

One very common procedure for dealing with the problem is simply this:

```
if r is a denormal
   r <- 0
```

This works fine when denormals are too small to have any effect on the the given algorithm, which is (pretty much) always.

I am looking to build for a number of platforms and would like to avoid these headaches before they happen to the greatest extent possible. So the question is, how do I identify/eliminate denormals in Haxe quickly and efficiently?

This might break down to other questions like: does Haxe have a language-specific method of handling denormals, or is it up to the platform? (I see nothing in the docs -- not even an isDenormal function) If it's up to the platform, is there a flag or something? How do I know which platforms need special handling, and which do not?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haxe doesn't support these operations. The problem is that most of the native platforms it addresses do not have any support for that either. I am talking mainly of JavaScript, Flash, PHP and Neko here.
You can certainly build your own library and try to optimize things where possible using inlines.

Comment: Okay, but in all those cases, I could at least be told via a flag/#define/etc what the platform characteristics for denormals are. As it is, I must build a lib with a #ifdef for each platform and do the denormal detection in far from optimal ways.

Comment: Well, you can always define a limit yourself: (( (x < 0) ? -x : x ) < 1e-15 ? 0 : x )

Comment: Bjorn, you can define this function by yourself like that: public  => static inline function needDenormFix() return #if java||php true #else false #end <=. Look into each platform specifications for exact list of "good" platforms. However, I believe just using your own code to handle this for all the platform won't hurt.

Comment: Oh, and everything will be inlined, so only one branch of if(needDenormFix()){}else{} will be compiled for each platform.